# Load Html Content if not exist JQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page with 3 buttons.    >Logos >Banners >Footer

When any of these 3 buttons clicked it does jquery post to a page which returns HTML content  in response and I set innerhtml of a div from that returned content . I want to do this so that If I clicked Logo and than went to Banner and come back on Logo it should not request for content again as its already loaded when clicked 1st time.

Thanks .

Comment: can you throw some HTML / js at our faces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="menu" data="logos" type="hidde-class">logos</a><br />
<a href="#" class="menu" data="banner" type="remover-class">banner</a><br />
<a href="#" class="menu" data="footer" type="remover-class">footer</a><br />

<div id="container"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(".menu").bind("click", function(event) {

    event.stopPropagation();

    var 
       data = $(this).attr("data");
       type = $(this).attr("type");

    if ($("#container").find(".logos").length > 0 && data == "logos") {
        $("#container").find(".logos").show();
        return false; 
    }

    var htmlappend = $("<div></div>")
                          .addClass(type)
                          .addClass(data);

    $("#container").find(".remover-class").remove();
    $("#container").find(".hidde-class").hide();

    $("#container").append(htmlappend);

    $("#container").find("." + data).load("file_" + data + "_.html");

    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the logic of the click handler, look for the content having been loaded. One way would be to see if you can find a particular element that comes in with the content.

Another would be to set a data- attribute on the elements with the click handler and look for the value of that attribute.

For example:

```
$(".myElements").click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("data-loaded") == false {
            // TODO: Do ajax load

            // Flag the elements so we don't load again
            $(".myElements").attr("data-loaded", true);
        }
    });
```

The benefit of storing the state in the data- attribute is that you don't have to use global variables and the data is stored within the DOM, rather than only in javascript. You can also use this to control script behavior with the HTML output by the server if you have a dynamic page.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like to be the perfect candidate for [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$(".someItem").one("click", function(){
  //do your post and load the html
});
```

Using one will allow for the event handler to trigger once per element.

Comment: I think the problem is that OP still needs to load the content, but since OP already made the call OP doesn't want to ajax load it again

Comment: .one() will un-bind the event handler on the element that was clicked on, but the other elements' event handlers will not be un-bound, and so the ajax will load again.

Comment: @hunter, very true, guess it depends on the overall intent of the page if the OP wants to swap out the html or simply load a div.

Comment: @cdeszaq, If each button would load different content `.one()` would work, but if each button loads the same content than it could be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could dump the returned html into a variable and then check if the variable is `null` before doing another ajax call

```
var logos = null;
var banners = null;
var footer = null;

$(".logos").click(function(){
    if (logos == null) // do ajax and save to logos variable
    else $("div").html(logos)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would unbind the click event when clicked to prevent further load requests

```
$('#button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#button').unbind('click');
    $('#result').load('ajax/test.html ' + 'someid', function() {
      //load callback
    });
});
```

or use one.click which is a better answer than this :)

Comment: You would need to un-bind the event handlers on the other elements as well.

Comment: I was thinking one button click per element, but yes your right if that's not the case

Answer (score 0):

Mark nailed it .one() will save extra line of codes and many checks hassle. I used it in a similar case. An optimized way to call that if they are wrapped in a parent container which I highly suggest will be:

```
$('#id_of_parent_container').find('button').one("click", function () {
    //get the id of the button that was clicked and do the ajax load accordingly
});
```